# Zxing JS zoom on Apple

Tags: javascript, deployment, zxing, zxing-js

I use decodeFromVideoDevice with zoom Parms {facingMode:"environment",zoom:4}.
On Android Devices it works but not on Apple.
Is there another parm or an option where I can use zoom in zxing js on Apple?

decodeFromVideoDevice with zoom Parms {facingMode:"environment",zoom:4} works on android but not ios